# Understanding BugSense usage in sending crash reports

Tags: objective-c, ios5, bug-tracking, bugsense

I have come across BugSense which I had implemented in one of my recent APP by generating a API in BugSense site. I had followed the DOC provided by BugSense and configured the tool successfully in my APP.

When I connect my device to my system and run my APP in debug mode, I see the below log in the console window.

```
BugSense --> Processing crash report...
BugSense --> Crashed on 2011-11-23 07:32:13 +0000
BugSense --> Crashed with signal SIGABRT (code #0, address=0x34417a1c)
BugSense --> Generating JSON data from crash report...
BugSense --> Posting JSON data...
BugSense --> Server responded with status code: 500
```

I want to know

- what crash report is generated.
- what JSON data it is posting.
- where my crash report is stored.

I had tried with some crash in my APP, but when I check the BugSense site for the progress I didn't see any graphical representation or error report.

What am i missing? How should I see the crash report? How do I send the crash log to BugSense so that I can see the crash report in the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution for my question, below is what I did

1. Turned off the GDB or LLDB in Edit Scheme and followed the steps provided by BugSense, here is the link [BugSense IOS integration steps](http://www.bugsense.com/docs/ios).
2. Then created a crash in my APP and tried running the APP, when the APP got crashed and I got the below response

> ```
> BugSense --> Processing crash report...
> BugSense --> Crashed on 2011-11-24 08:49:04 +0000
> BugSense --> Crashed with signal SIGSEGV (code SEGV_MAPERR, address=0xbbadbeef)
> BugSense --> Generating JSON data from crash report...
> BugSense --> Posting JSON data...
> BugSense --> Server responded with status code: 200
> BugSense --> Immediate dispatch completed!
> ```

Now I can send crash reports to BugSense and see the detailed report about the crash.